# Using ODBC package to access SQL Express from R on Mac vs PC

Tags: r, macos, odbc

I've been trying to set up a remote SQL Express database to test analysis work I've been doing (the full dataset is a full SQL Server build but for IG purposes I'm trying to do a minimal test setup in-house). I have a copy of the latest version of SQL Express set up on an old PC. My primary development environment is on the Mac, but I've got Bootcamp installed on it.

I installed the MS SQL ODBC driver for Mac from the Microsoft website, and have been trying to use the ODBC package following the instructions on https://db.rstudio.com.

After initial attempts failed, I tested the local setup of the SQL Server, following Microsoft's troubleshooting guide.

I then switched using Bootcamp to Windows, installed RStudio on there, and ran the same line of code (below) with the Windows version of the driver name, with success.

I've disabled the firewall to ensure that this wasn't interfering. I've pinged `Test-PC` and confirmed that the IP address works as expected. The error I get is as below.

Could anyone suggest where to go / look next?

```
library(odbc)

> odbc::odbcListDrivers()
                           name   attribute                                   value
1 ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server Description Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
2 ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server      Driver    /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib
3 ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server  UsageCount    

> con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver="ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server", Server = "Test-PC/SQLEXPRESS", UID = "my_user", PWD = "my_password", Port = 1433)

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: HYT00: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
```

Comment: Try removing the `Port = 1433` *or* changing `Server = "Test-PC/SQLEXPRESS"` to `Server = "Test-PC"`.  (Also note that when targeting a named instance, the separator between machine and instance name is usually the backslash `\`, not the solidus `/` -- so changing `Server = "Test-PC/SQLEXPRESS"` to `Server = "Test-PC\SQLEXPRESS"` might also do the job.)

Comment: Just tried all combinations of the above - still get the same result :-(.